# How to save current CustomUser as person field in my Melk model? There is OneToMany relation

Tags: python, django-views

I am curious to solve this problem.
I use  CustomUser
I have 2 models CustomUser and Melk
In my forms.py, when i use 'person' as field, it means user can see all the users but I want current user fill the form and based on onetomany relation, person field fills by id of current user.

I deleted 'person' field in forms and tried to use of 
`form.users_melk.person_id = request.user` or 
`Melk.objects.create(person_id = user_id)`
but it does not solved.

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
     def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Melk(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    type_deal= models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    person = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

**forms.py**

```
class MelkForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Melk
        fields = ('category', 'type_deal', 'person')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="home")
def  melk_new(request):
    f = MelkForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        f.save()        
    return render(request,'melk_new.html', { 'form': f})
```

When i delete 'person' field in forms.py this error appears:

> IntegrityError at /users/melk_new/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   users_melk.person_id Request Method:  POST Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/melk_new/ Django Version:   2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem `f.person= request.user.id`

Comment: person was person_id and I tried to save something instead of person  which was not integer.